# Establish a session to call URL with Perl

Tags: perl, session-cookies, www-mechanize, web-mining, www-authenticate

I am trying to mine data from a webpage with the WWW::Mechanize perl module. However, I first need to establish a connection so that this webpage will allow me to access the data. In a browser, I can establish this connection by clicking a particular href link. Is there a way to do this with Perl?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Clicking href links is what Mechanize does.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a handy [passage about following links](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize#mech-follow_link) from the WWW::Mechanize manual.